# Install python with given version using Miniconda

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, conda, environment, miniconda

I use Raspberry Pi.

I tried to create an environment with this:

```
conda create --name "myenv" python=3.10.1 mediapipe
```

I got the following error:

```
Fetching package metadata: ....
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: python 3.10.1*

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda python 3.10.1*

You may need to install the anaconda-client command line client with

    conda install anaconda-client
```

I think miniconda thinks python=3.10.1 is a package.

Comment: Does this work with python=3.8 as an alternative?

Comment: also, try to remove quotes from myenv: "myenv" -> myenv

Comment: @rikyeah Does not work: conda create --name "myenv" python=3.8

Comment: @rikyeah Does not work without quotes: conda create --name myenv python=3.8

Comment: does https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html help? what is mediapipe by the way?

Comment: @rikyeah mediapipe is a package.
This also not works: conda create --name "asdasd" mediapipe

Comment: This does not work as well: conda create --name "asdasd" opencv-python
Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching: opencv-python

Answer (score 1):

[No one maintains Conda for 32-bit Raspberry Pi](https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda) (platform **linux-armv7l**). Basically you're stuck with what is on [the **rpi** channel](https://anaconda.org/rpi) or works with `noarch`, and that means at latest Python 3.6.6.

The newer full 64-bit OS images for Raspberry Pi 4 should be compatible with **linux-aarch64** builds from Conda Forge, and those are actively maintained (e.g., `python=3.10.2` is available).

BTW, Conda does treat `python=3.10.1` as a package because *it is a package*. That is, Conda is a general package manager and Python has no special treatment (aside from the bit of bootstrapping that Conda itself is a Python package).